# vbscript not working into client machine

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

I have this in my html file:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
    Function FormatADateUsingLocale(aDate)
        Dim vbDate vbDate = DateValue (aDate)
        FormatADateUsingLocale = FormatDateTime(vbDate, 2)
</script>
```

This is called from same HTML file JavaScript function:

```
function buildMenuBar(){ 
    aDs = FormatADateUsingLocale("1899/12/23"); 
    alert(aDs);
}
```

It work fine on most of the machine. But on one of the machines I see this error: `aDs is undefined`.

Comment: Is it a typo, or have you actually not ended your function? (I've formatted it to make the missing `End Function` statement more obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some typo in your vbs code, lets say they're during copy/paste, but it's good to mention them.

1. Most obvious is that you have missing `End Function`.
2. At `Dim` line I see 2 issues.

First `vbDate` is preserved constant in VBScript. It's a good idea to not use "vb" at front of your variable names.

Second, declaration and initiation are 2 separate processes/commands, that mean...

```
' next is incorrect
Dim x = 0

' next is correct
Dim x
x = 0

' next is correct too, but not recommendable
Dim x : x = 0
```

Ok, probably missing colon (`:`) in that line is also a typo.

You can pass string litteral values directly to `FormatDateTime` function without explicit conversion. It's more important to check is the passed argument to your function can be converted to `vbDate` with `IsDate` function, else the `DateValue` too will fail with "Type mismatch" error. So, to end with complete function should predict as well what it will return in case the argument cannot be converted to valid `vbDate` type.

```
' shortly, something like this
Function FormatADateUsingLocale(ByVal aDate)
    If Not IsDate(aDate) Then aDate = "9999/12/31"
    FormatADateUsingLocale = FormatDateTime(aDate, 2)
End Function
```

This is the base idea of course, you may wish to return empty string or something else in case passed argument is "invalid".

Comment: Thanks for the solution it worked. Sorry for the late update :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a line number for the error or the exact error message that you are getting? Within the buildMenuBar() function, aDs should just be treated as an implicitly declared global variable. This should just be a warning that something is not quite right, not an error.

If I add in a JavaScript function like below then I get "Not implemented" displayed in an alert box as expected.

```
function buildMenuBar() {
    aDs = FormatADateUsingLocale("1899/12/23");
    alert(aDs);
}
function FormatADateUsingLocale (p) {
     return "Not implemented";
};
```

Comment: Error is coming as aDs is undefined in buildMenuBar() function. where as on the top i have define var aDs = null;